# AndroidManifest from Jars

Tags: android, jar, shared-libraries

Is it possible to have an AndroidManifest.xml and or resource files in a Jar file and import that into a executable Android project?

My goal is to provide styles, resources, and services from a jar library that can be accessed from a main android project for my common tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services and other Java classes, yes. Styles, resources, `AndroidManifest.xml` -- no.

Comment: A big shortcoming in my opinion, but the current way it works.